# Why are there missing .dll files while installing?

Tags: windows-7, dll

My system is Windows 7, 64-bit. Recently I tried to install some Weather Channel desktop app on my wife's user account. The installer said I was missing two `.dll` files.

I ran a system scan and it didn't indicate any problems.

My question is, are those `.dll` files missing because of some corrupion or error, or should `.dll`'s always be provided in the app "package"?

Comment: Which DLL's did it say it was missing?  Could be expecting .NET framework (or a specific version), or perhaps C++ or VB run-times, etc.

Comment: I'll have to take a look tonight.  I actually dl'd them and copied them to the system folder.

Comment: If you just downloaded and copied them into place, then you may still have to register them with the system using `regsvr32` or alike.

Comment: Sure, but does the fact that they were missing indicate a lack of integrity in the system?

Comment: You haven't told us which DLL's, nor cleared up how you replaced them, so it's hard to make any kind of guesses.  If it was one of the common runtime/framework packages from MS, and you successfully installed it via normal methods, you should be fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

The .NET Framework 3.5 is included with Windows 7.

If you in fact downloaded whatever missing files were given to you in the error message, this will either:

1) Work fine after you register them like such:

Press Meta+R (Windows key + R) to bring up the run dialog box, type in "regsvr32 c:\whereveryouputthedllfiles"

or

2) Fail because they are the wrong versions of the file.

Comment: Strangely enough, it the install went through just fine.  The app is crap so I deleted it.

Comment: lol, good to know...